# Bottom Navigation bar with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

I have a bottom navigation bar in my Main Activity. By clicking on one of the tabs in my bottom navigation, I want to change the fragment in the view. I have the following code:
Main Activity:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SwiftFragment swiftFragment;
FrameworksFragment frameworksFragment;
FrameLayout content;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                Log.i("Nachricht", "HOME");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_swift:
                Log.i("Nachricht", "SWIFT");
                transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, swiftFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_frameworks:
                Log.i("Nachricht", "FRAMEWORKS");
                transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, frameworksFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                Log.i("Nachricht", "PROFILE");
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    swiftFragment = (SwiftFragment) android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(this, SwiftFragment.class.getName(), null);
    frameworksFragment = (FrameworksFragment) android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(this, FrameworksFragment.class.getName(), null);
    content = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

}

One of my fragments:

```
public class SwiftFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<ModelTutorial> items;
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_swift, container, false);

    //TODO: Get Firebase Data
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(new ModelTutorial("Swift Anlegen der Liste", "TableView", "Test Test Test", null, null));
    items.add(new ModelTutorial("Anlegen der Liste", "TableView", "Test Test Test", null, null));
    items.add(new ModelTutorial("Anlegen der Liste", "TableView", "Test Test Test", null, null));

    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.swiftTutorialsList);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

}
```

If I click on one of the tabs, the right fragment shows up, so this is working. However when the new fragment shows up and I want to click on another tab to show another fragment, this doesn't work. The bottom navigation bar doesn't react on the clicks. Even the `Log.i` statements doesn't work, so it seems the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` isn't called.

I'm completely new to android development and I don't understand why this isn't working. I would appreciate it if someone could help me with my problem.

EDIT: XML File StartActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.marcelspindler.codingtutorials.StartActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML File Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.marcelspindler.codingtutorials.SwiftFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/swiftTutorialsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also add xml file? Check if your listener is actually getting called but returning false, in that case it won't log.

Comment: Need xml layout and i think it would be error in xml because your replacing fragment with `android.R.id.content` when you do that it will replace entire window for example check by putting color for fragment background

Comment: I edited my question and added the XML files. @RickSanchez I tried to log when it returns false, but this is never called. @HermanSTobi I changed the backgroundcolor and you're right, it covers the whole window, also the bottom navigation bar. Do you know a way to avoid that if `android.R.id.content` doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the Fragment to a container inside your MainActivity.

Try something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.marcelspindler.codingtutorials.StartActivity">

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then replace your replace lines to:

`transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);`

**BONUS**: You can initiate your fragments like this:
`swiftFragment =  new SwiftFragment();`

Take look to this after: 
[Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)